# "Альтер()эго": слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография

Что-то не могу сообразить, как пишется "альтер()эго": слитно или раздельно? По идее, это два слова, но как по правилам?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ни разу не видел, чтобы кто-то писал слитно. Да в общем-то и причин на то нет.
Иногда пишут в одно слово используя как имя собственное (название фирмы, сетевой ник и проч), но это скорее следствие моды, на нарицательное значение не распространяется.

Answer (score 3):

По Лопатину в два слова, без дефиса [**АЛЬТЕР ЭГО**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%E0%EB%FC%F2%E5%F0-%FD%E3%EE&all=x).